# Remove last character in regex .replace

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I'm trying to detect numbers followed by "." and then wrap them in a `<span>` without that last "."

So far, this is what I have:

```
$(".item_title").each(function(index) {
    var t = $(this).html().replace(/(^\d+\.)/g, "<span>$1</span>");  
    $(this).html(t);
});
```

But I end up with `<span>5.</span>` and I'm looking for `<span>5</span>`

Also, is the way I'm doing the regex replace correct and efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: Take the `.` out of the grouping …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for a positive lookahead such as `([0-9]+)(?=\.)`.

```
var t = $(this).html().replace(/([0-9]+)(?=\.)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
```

Which will turn

```
This is my string. It is a nice string. I have a total of bananas 5. Yes. 5 bananas.
```

into

```
This is my string. It is a nice string. I have a total of bananas <span>5</span>. Yes. 5 bananas.
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/cP5rY5)

**or** if you want the dot to disappear, just move it out of the group:

```
var t = $(this).html().replace(/(^\d+)\./g, "<span>$1</span>");  
//                                    ^^
```

Which would turn out string into the following (notice the dot is gone):

```
This is my string. It is a nice string. I have a total of bananas <span>5</span> Yes. 5 bananas.
```

Comment: I need to match only numbers at the start, so I used ^. The thing with the dot is that i need to hide it/remove it from the string.

Comment: @Santiago Then simply `var t = $(this).html().replace(/^([0-9]+)\./g, "<span>$1</span>");`

Comment: Last question: If I want to remove all characters that aren't numbers after the dot, is this possible? I mean: `12345.-/ apples` would become `<span>12345</span> apples`

Comment: @Santiago `/^([0-9]+)[^\d\s]+/g` should work. `[^\d\s]` means "characters that aren't a digit or a space/tab/newline character".

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dot to be removed then put it out of the parenthesis

```
"5. some text 80.".replace(/(\d+)\s*\./g, "<span>$1</span>"); // \s* is needed if numbers can be followed by spaces
```

Comment: Last question: If I want to remove all characters that aren't numbers after the dot, is this possible? I mean: `12345.-/ apples` would become `<span>12345</span> apples`

Comment: Sure ! Try this ... `"5. some text 80.-/ apple".replace(/(\d+)\s*\..+? +\b/g, "<span>$1</span> ")`